# Java Code for calculating Leap Year

Tags: java, leap-year, acm-java-libraries

I am following "The Art and Science of Java" book and it shows how to calculate a leap year.
The book uses ACM Java Task Force's library.

Here is the code the books uses:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class LeapYear extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run()
    {

        println("This program calculates leap year.");
        int year = readInt("Enter the year: ");     

        boolean isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));

        if (isLeapYear)
        {
            println(year + " is a leap year.");
        } else
            println(year + " is not a leap year.");
    }

}
```

Now, this is how I calculated the leap year.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class LeapYear extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run()
    {

        println("This program calculates leap year.");
        int year = readInt("Enter the year: ");

        if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0)
        {
            println(year + " is a leap year.");
        }
        else if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0))
        {
            println(year + " is a leap year.");
        }
        else
        {
            println(year + " is not a leap year.");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or should i use the one provided by the book ?

EDIT :: Both of the above code works fine, What i want to ask is which code is the best way to calculate the leap year.

Comment: Best code would be to use a trusted library instead.  Cletus suggestion of using the Calendar class is a prime example hereof.

Comment: You are correct if Im using the regular Java library. But in my course, im using ACM's Java Task Force's library.

http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/

Comment: Here is similar thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395699/calculate-leap-year-in-java/7395759#7395759

Comment: The method from the book is for the Gregorian Calendar, your method is just wrong (leap year every 400 years only?) and every four years would be for the Julian Calendar.

Comment: if((year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 == 0) && year % 100 != 0){ println(year +" is leap year") }

Comment: @dipu That fails for multiples of 400.

Comment: [`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) is your friend. See [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37380349/642706).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The correct implementation is:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
  return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 365;
}
```

But if you are going to reinvent this wheel then:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
  if (year % 4 != 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using library code.  I would suggestion adding a note on it is because that 400 is a multiplum of 100 that you test for 400 before 100 as opposed to the original code.

Comment: @cletus where is the DAY_OF_YEAR value passed to cal.getActualMaximum();

Comment: that line should be `cal.getActualMaximum(cal.DAY_OF_YEAR);`

Comment: +1 for @OlofuMark for pointing that out. but a minor change: it should be `Calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);` because `DAY_OF_YEAR` is a static member and therefore, should be accessed in a static way. =)

Comment: or `return year % 100 == 0 ? year % 400 == 0 : year % 4 == 0;`

Comment: Even better - `return new GregorianCalendar(year, 1, 1).isLeapYear();`

Comment: What if  `else if (year % 400 == 0)` statement is omitted? Wouldn't it give same results?

Comment: You can't beat `return ((year & 3) == 0 && ((year % 25) != 0 || (year & 15) == 0));` for efficiency. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595914/733805

Comment: This doesn't work for BC years. Since adapted code in this answer that handles BC years as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53712875/274677

Answer (score 44):

## `java.time.Year::isLeap`

I'd like to add the new [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) way of doing this with the [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) class and [`isLeap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#isLeap()) method:

```
java.time.Year.of(year).isLeap();
```

Comment: Is current year a leap year? (using java 8) `Year.now().isLeap()`

Comment: @SheamusO'Halloran Better to specify your desired/expected time zone rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone which can be changed at any moment by any code in any app within that JVM: `Year.now( ZoneId( "America/Montreal" ) ).isLeap()`

Comment: `Year.isLeap(<YEAR>)`  Using Java 8 to directly check is the input year is a leap year or not.

Answer (score 31):

I suggest you put this code into a method and create a unit test.

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    assert year >= 1583; // not valid before this date.
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}
```

In the unit test

```
assertTrue(isLeapYear(2000));
assertTrue(isLeapYear(1904));
assertFalse(isLeapYear(1900));
assertFalse(isLeapYear(1901));
```

Comment: If I were a lecturer, I'd teach unit testing first. In maths and engineering maths classes, it's normal practice to put the results back through the formulas to check them; unit testing is getting the computer to do the same thing for your program.

Comment: Im following Standfords Programming Methodology Video course, the lecturer is using The Art and Science of Java book to teach the methodology of programming rather than teach Java. 

Im on chapter 4 and still there is no topic on Unit Testing so far.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, why are years before 1583 not valid?

Comment: @jcw 1583 was the first year of the Gregorian Calendar.  Different countries adopted it in different years, making year between 1583 and the year it was adopted more complicated. (A idea of how confusing it can be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_30) In any case, it doesn't make sense to use the Gregorian Calendar before it was created.

Answer (score 12):

```
new GregorianCalendar().isLeapYear(year);
```

Answer (score 11):

Pseudo code from Wikipedia translated into the most compact Java

```
(year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))
```

Comment: Just for having said it: Please always include a link to any source that you used to compile an answer (even if it's easy to find like Wikipedia content).

Answer (score 6):

## Most Efficient Leap Year Test:

```
if ((year & 3) == 0 && ((year % 25) != 0 || (year & 15) == 0))
{
    /* leap year */
}
```

This is an excerpt from my detailed answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595914/733805

Answer (score 5):

From JAVA's GregorianCalendar sourcecode:

```
/**
 * Returns true if {@code year} is a leap year.
 */
public boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year > changeYear) {
        return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
    }

    return year % 4 == 0;
}
```

Where changeYear is the year the Julian Calendar becomes the Gregorian Calendar (1582).

> The Julian calendar specifies leap years every four years, whereas the
>   Gregorian calendar omits century years which are not divisible by 400.

In the [Gregorian Calendar documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) you can found more information about it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using java8 :

```
java.time.Year.of(year).isLeap()
```

Java implementation of above method:

```
public static boolean isLeap(long year) {
        return ((year & 3) == 0) && ((year % 100) != 0 || (year % 400) == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's almost always wrong to have repetition in software. In any engineering discipline, form should follow function, and you have three branches for something which has two possible paths - it's either a leap year or not.

The mechanism which has the test on one line doesn't have that issue, but generally it would be better to separate the test into a function which takes an int representing a year and returns a boolean representing whether or not the year is a leap year. That way you can do something with it other that print to standard output on the console, and can more easily test it.

In code which is known to exceed its performance budget, it's usual to arrange the tests so that they are not redundant and perform the tests in an order which returns early. The wikipedia example does this - for most years you have to calculate modulo 400,100 and 4, but for a few you only need modulo 400 or 400 and 100. This is a small optimisation in terms of performance ( at best, only one in a hundred inputs are effected ), but it also means the code has less repetition, and there's less for the programmer to type in.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#isLeapYear(int)) class for this:

```
boolean isLeapyear = new GregorianCalendar().isLeapYear(year);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the course of  : [TestMyCode
Programming assignment evaluator](https://tmc.mooc.fi/), that one of the exercises was this kind of issue, I wrote this answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a year: ");

        int year = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if (year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 == 0 && year % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.println("The year is a leap year");
        } else
         if (year % 4 == 0 && year%100!=0 ) {
            System.out.println("The year is a leap year");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("The year is not a leap year");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. There is an added function to check to see if the int is past the date on which the exceptions were imposed(year$100, year %400). Before 1582 those exceptions weren't around.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lecture{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean loop=true;
    Scanner console = new Scanner( System.in );
    while (loop){
        System.out.print( "Enter the year: " );

        int year= console.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "The year is a leap year: "+ leapYear(year) );
        System.out.print( "again?: " );
        int again = console.nextInt();
        if (again == 1){
            loop=false;
        }//if
    }
}
public static boolean leapYear ( int year){
    boolean leaped = false;
    if (year%4==0){
        leaped = true;
        if(year>1582){
            if (year%100==0&&year%400!=0){
                leaped=false;
            }
        }
    }//1st if
    return leaped;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

String strDate="Feb 2013";
        String[] strArray=strDate.split("\\s+");        

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").parse(strArray[0].toString()));
        int monthInt = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        monthInt++;
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(strArray[1]));          
        strDate=strArray[1].toString()+"-"+monthInt+"-"+cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        System.out.println(strDate);    



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the year then press Enter : ");
        int year = input.nextInt();

        if ((year < 1580) && (year % 4 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("Leap year: " + year);
        } else {
            if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
                System.out.println("Leap year: " + year);
            } else {
                System.out.println(year + " not a leap year!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) states algorithm for the leap year should be

```
(((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 !=0)) || (year%400==0))
```

Here is a sample program [how to check for leap year](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/05/c-program-to-check-leap-year.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as it is, without an additional class, does not appear to work for universal java.
Here is a simplified version that works anywhere, leaning more towards your code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year;
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter year: ");
            year = scan.nextInt();

            if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0) {
                System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
            } else if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0)
                    && (year % 400 == 0)) {
                System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your code, in context, works just as well, but note that book code *always works*, and is tested thoroughly. Not to say yours isn't. :)

Answer (score 0):

easiest way ta make java leap year and more clear to understand`enter code here`

```
import  java.util.Scanner;
```

class que19{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    double a;

    System.out.println("enter the year here ");
    a=input.nextDouble();
    if ((a % 4 ==0 ) && (a%100!=0) || (a%400==0)) {
        System.out.println("leep year");

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("not a leap year");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021373/274677) is great but it won't work for years before Christ (using a proleptic Gregorian calendar). If you want it to work for B.C. years, then use the following adaptation:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(final int year) {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (year<0) {
        cal.set(Calendar.ERA, GregorianCalendar.BC);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, -year);
    } else
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 365;
}
```

You can verify that for yourself by considering that year -5 (i.e. 4 BC) should be pronounced as a leap year assuming a proleptic Gregorian calendar. Same with year -1 (the year before 1 AD). The linked to answer does not handle that case whereas the above adapted code does.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun isLeapYear(year: Int): Boolean =
    when {
        year % 4 != 0 -> false
        year % 100 == 0 -> year % 400 == 0
        else -> true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from Clean Code book by Martin R.

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
   boolean fourth = year % 4 == 0;
   boolean hundredth = year % 100 == 0;
   boolean fourHundredth = year % 400 == 0;
   return fourth && (!hundredth || fourHundredth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Method 1:`

```
public class LeapYear {

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){

        return ( !(year >= 1) ? false : (year%4 != 0) ? false : (year%100 != 0) ? true : (year%400 == 0) ? true : false ); 
    }

}
```

`Method 2:`

```
public class LeapYear {

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
        
        return ( (year >= 1) && ( (year%4 == 0 && !(year%100 == 0)) || (year%400 == 0) )? true : false );
        
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year;
String yearStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter radius: " );

year = Integer.parseInt( yearStr );

boolean isLeapYear;
isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);  

 if(isLeapYear){ 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Leap Year!"); 
 }  
 else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a Leap Year!"); 
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
boolean leapYear = ( ( year % 4 ) == 0 );
```

Comment: Only one condition mentioned above is not enough to identify a leap year. The above is wrong. So you have to apply more conditions answered by The Sphinc: (year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))