# Calculate leap year in Java

Tags: java, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Code for calculating Leap Year, is this code correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021324/java-code-for-calculating-leap-year-is-this-code-correct)

This was homework, and I have already received my grade, but I did not implement leap years in my code. This is a simple program that displays the numbers in a month based on user input. The only thing is I can't figure out is a way to implement a leap year that would get 29 days for February rather than 28, without writing multiple `if` statements. Surely there is an easier way? Here is the code:

```
//Displays number of days in a month

package chapter_3;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Chapter_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This program will calculate \n"
                + "the number of days in a month based upon \n"
                + "your input, when prompted please enter \n"
                + "the numerical value of the month you would like\n"
                + "to view including the year. Example: if you would like\n"
                + "to view March enter 3 2011 and so on.");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt user for month and year
        System.out.print("Please enter the month and year: ");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        int year = input.nextInt();

        if (month == 1) {
            System.out.println("January " + year + " has 31 days");
        }   
        else if (month == 2) {
            System.out.println("February " + year + " has 28 days");
        }   
        else if (month == 3) {
            System.out.println("March " + year + " has 31 days");
        }
        else if (month == 4) {
            System.out.println("April " + year + " has 30 days");
        }
        else if (month == 5) {
            System.out.println("May " + year + " has 31 days");
        }
        else if (month == 6) {
            System.out.println("June " + year + " has 30 days");
        }
        else if (month == 7) {
            System.out.println("July " + year + " has 31 days");
        }
        else if (month == 8) {
            System.out.println("August " + year + " has 31 days");
        }
        else if (month == 9) {
            System.out.println("September " + year + " has 30 days");
         }
        else if (month == 10) {
            System.out.println("October " + year + " has 30 days");
        }
        else if (month == 11) {
            System.out.println("November " + year + " has 30 days");
        }
        else if (month == 12) {
            System.out.println("December " + year + " has 31 days");
         }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter the numerical value "
                + "of the month you would like to view");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use the [`GregorianCalendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), you could do as below

> Determines if the given year is a leap year. Returns true if the given
>   year is a leap year. To specify BC year numbers, 1 - year number must
>   be given. For example, year BC 4 is specified as -3.

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

if(cal.isLeapYear(year))
{
    System.out.print("Given year is leap year.");
}
else
{ 
    System.out.print("Given year is not leap year.");
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Quoting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

> Years that are evenly divisible by 100 are not leap years, unless they
>   are also evenly divisible by 400, in which case they are leap years.

So if you want to reinvent the wheel:

```
boolean isLeapYear = year%4 == 0 && (year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0)
```

But the most elegant solution (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021324/java-code-for-calculating-leap-year-is-this-code-correct/1021373#1021373)) is probably

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
  return cal.getActualMaximum(DAY_OF_YEAR) > 365;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use a switch statment, with a few if statements inside the february case:

```
switch(month)
{
case 1:
    System.out.println("January " + year + " has 31 days");
    break;
case 2:
    int n=28;
    if(year%4==0 && (year%100!=0 || year%400==0)
        n++;
    System.out.println("February " + year + " has "+n+" days");
    break;
case 3:
    System.out.println("March " + year + " has 31 days");
    break;
case 4:
    System.out.println("April " + year + " has 30 days");
    break;
case 5:
    System.out.println("May " + year + " has 31 days");
    break;
case 6:
    System.out.println("June " + year + " has 30 days");
    break;
case 7:
    System.out.println("July " + year + " has 31 days");
    break;
case 8:
    System.out.println("August " + year + " has 31 days");
    break;
case 9:
    System.out.println("September " + year + " has 30 days");
    break;
case 10:
    System.out.println("October " + year + " has 30 days");
    break;
case 11:
    System.out.println("November " + year + " has 30 days");
    break;
case 12:
    System.out.println("December " + year + " has 31 days");
    break;
default case:
    System.out.println("Please enter the numerical value of the month you would like to view");
}
```

see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html for more info