# Having trouble writing code that can calculate the leap year

Tags: java, operation, leap-year

Directions:
"A year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4. But if the year is divisible by 100, it is a leap year only when it is also divisible by 400.

Create a program that checks whether the given year is a leap year." I am having most trouble with getting the calculations part down. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int year;

    System.out.print("Type a year:");
    year=Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    if ((year%4==0)||(((year%100==year%400)))){

      System.out.println("The year a leap year.");
 }else       
       System.out.println("The year is not a leap year.");

}
```

I don't receive errors when I run the code, however, when I put such dates, 1600, 1601, and 1700 etc it says it is a leap year when it should not be. I'm very lost and any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your `||` should be an `&&`.

Comment: The || must be &&

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine leap year using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967390/determine-leap-year-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0`

Comment: thank you, the code works 100%. Can you please explain what I did wrong that prevented my code to not print correctly. And the operator "!," I never really understood what it was meant for, can you explain how that "!" works in this case? Thank you again! :)

Comment: @AMCgiftcard The order matters. In your case, you first checked whether ```year``` is divisible by 4 (which is always ```true``` for every number divisible by 100).

Also, checking for equality in ```year % 100 == year % 400``` is not a good thing, since it returns ```true``` even for 1601 or 2003 (because remainder of division both by 100 and 400 is the same).

In the code above it first checks if ```year``` is divisible by 4 *and* not divisible by 100. This means we are working with the first case only (the second being the numbers divisible by 100).

Comment: Oh, okay that makes a lot more sense! Thank you again!