# Check leap years with Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm stuck using the **and** operator, how can you test for multiple conditions. I am very close but am stuck to solving this with clojure.

```
(defn leap [year] (cond (and (zero? (rem year 4)) (zero? (rem year 100))) true :else false))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you’ve solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. You should *not* simply edit your question with the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using `and` properly, but your logic is wrong and should not be using `and`

```
(defn leap
  [year]
  (cond (zero? (mod year 400)) true
        (zero? (mod year 100)) false
        (zero? (mod year 4)) true
        :default false))
```

(this is according to the rules for leap years in the Gregorian Calendar as listed on the [wikipedia page for Leap Year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)).

I have avoided any usage of nested logic operators because the purpose of `cond` is to simplify what would otherwise be a complex nested conditional into a linear sequence of choices where the first appropriate choice is selected.

Ideally one should be using a library like [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) for any time / date logic, because these things are always much harder than anticipated to do properly and generally.

Additionally, one could use `condp`, though in this case I think it obfuscates more than it clarifies:

```
(condp #(zero? (mod %2 %))
    year
  400 true
  100 false
  4 true
  false)
```

Answer (score 4):

Don’t reinvent the wheel, use [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time)’s [`number-of-days-in-the-month`](http://clj-time.github.io/clj-time/doc/clj-time.core.html#var-number-of-days-in-the-month):

```
(require 'clj-time.core)

(defn leap-year? [year]
  (= 29 (clj-time.core/number-of-days-in-the-month year 2)))
```

or alternatively:

```
(defn leap-year? [year]
  (= 366 (clj-time.core/in-days
           (clj-time.core/interval (clj-time.core/date-time year 1 1)
                                   (clj-time.core/date-time (+ 1 year) 1 1)))))
```

Comment: Or `(import java.util.Calendar)` and `(defn leap-year? [year] (-> (doto (Calendar/getInstance) (.set Calendar/YEAR year)) (.getActualMaximum Calendar/DAY_OF_YEAR) (> 365)))`

Comment: @A.Webb Which, for reference, is the same algorithm from [Java Code for calculating Leap Year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021373/211563).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a case (what happens if the year is divisible by 400?), and the first condition isn't right. Here's another approach, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595914/201359) answer:

```
(defn leap [year]
  (cond (not (zero? (mod year 4)))   false
        (not (zero? (mod year 100))) true
        (zero? (mod year 400))       true
        :else false))
```

Also from the same link, here's another potentially faster solution, albeit much harder to understand:

```
(defn leap [year]
  (and (zero? (bit-and year 3))
       (or (not (zero? (mod year 25)))
           (zero? (bit-and year 15)))))
```

Comment: I like the source, and for those who are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220163/how-to-find-leap-year-programatically-in-c/11595914#11595914

Answer (score 0):

Better, I think, without explicit `true` and `false`:

```
(defn leap? [year]
  (let [div? #(->> % (mod year) zero?)]
    (and (div? 4) (or (not (div? 100)) (div? 400)))))
```

We can maybe make it clearer by defining

```
(defmacro implies [p q] (or (not p) q))
```

... and expressing the body of the function thus:

```
(and (div? 4) (implies (div? 100) (div? 400)))
```

---

Note: `leap?` is a predicate, so conventionally ends with `?`.