Is there a java.time equivalent of DateTime.dayOfYear().isLeap()?
We have some code which checks whether a given day is a leap day using org.joda.time. It is simply
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

DateTime date;
return date.dayOfYear().isLeap()

Is there an equivalent in the java.time package that checks whether a given date is leap day?
I can't find the question asked anywhere on the site and hard-coding February 29 seems bad to me for some reason. I thought I was just overlooking something and thought this would be a good place to ask.
We only use the Gregorian (ISO 8601) calendar, though we do operate internationally.

What about java.time.Year.isLeap()?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37380349/2055998

What about something like boolean isLeapDay(LocalDateTime ldt) { return Year.isLeap(ldt.getYear()) && ldt.getMonth() == Month.FEBRUARY && ldt.getDayOfMonth() == 29; }?

@g00se why even include the leap part? Feb 29th only exists in leap years, so just check for that.

yes, @g00se, that will work.

@Progman I'm looking for whether a date is  is leap day, not leap year.

not sure why all the down votes. I can't find the question asked anywhere on the site and hard-coding February 29 seems bad to me for some reason. I thought I was just overlooking something and thought this would be a good place to ask.

Hehe, yes, the year check in my code is redundant

Hello Kirby, You are a bit confused, there are no leap days (a day cannot have an extra day), only years can be leap days.

This REALLY feels like the root of the question lies in a bad design choice. Also, as others have stated multiple times, Feb 29th is not a universal 'leap day', so this problem/code will fail as soon as you leave Western calendars (Gregorian, for example). Better specify the REASON why you would want to identify said 'leap days'.

@MarcePuente, "February 29 is a leap day (or "leap year day")—an intercalary date added periodically to create leap years in the Julian and Gregorian calendars" – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29

As for the Down-Votes, every good Question gets down-votes on Stack Overflow — just the weird ways of Stack Overflow. Then later Up-Votes roll in. This happens so consistently that  I have wondered if it might be a bot, internal or external…

In the calendar used in Iran and Afghanistan, the "leap day" is 30 Esfand, which is the 12th month, and which has only 29 days in non-leap years. JayC667 was correct to point out that if you leave the Gregorian and Julian calendars behind, you can't rely on leap day being 29 February. I'm quite disturbed to see @BasilBourque incorrectly categorising JayC667's correct statement as "utter nonsense" and using the phrase "any grade-school child" to mean "grade school children in western countries". This is an international web site, not a "westerners only" site, and this feels to me like racism.

@DawoodibnKareem While you got my fur up with an absurd accusation of racism, I did take a moment to re-read the Question. I had assumed the Question mentioned February 29th explicitly, which would obviously imply the specific calendar system of Gregorian. Now I see that the Question does not mention February 29 explicitly. The Question originally mentions Leap Day generically. So the cross-calendar-system issue is indeed valid to raise. On that point, I stand corrected. I deleted my contentious Comment. My apologies to JayC667 for misinterpreting that Comment as pedantic.

Where I come from the leap day is not February 29. I have seen it fall on February 24, but I don’t know whether it does in all leap years. And I don’t know what Joda-Time counts as leap day.

Was leap day ever officially observed on February 24? [closed] on Stack Exchange

But if you want February 29: Declare static final MonthDay LEAP_DAY = MonthDay.of(Month.FEBRUARY, 29);. Then compare MonthDay.from(yourDateTime).equals(LEAP_DAY). Will work for LocalDate, ZonedDateTime and many other java.time types.

@Anonymous I doubt it will work directly with ZonedDateTime as the leap day is not an instant

@g00se For MonthDay you just need a month and a day of month, which a ZonedDateTime defines (even though it defines an instant too). It works.

For the general (non-Gregorian) case that you didn’t ask about, one may consider using the lengthOfMonth method for the date last year and next year, and if the day of the month is past one of those lengths, it’s probably a leap day. It’s not bullet-proof, possibly no solution can be, and possibly not all calendars even have a hard-and-fast definition of what a leap day is. lengthOfMonth() is declared in ChronoLocalDate, the interface implemented by dates of all implemented chronologies (calendar systems).

I like that lengthOfMonth comparison idea

Is the date February 29th?
The java.time API only has the java.time.Year::isLeap method; no day-based isLeap method.
If you want to find if a day is a leap day, then you can just check if the day is February 29th. That date only exists in a leap year.
boolean isLeapDay(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
  return dateTime.getMonth() == Month.FEBRUARY 
      && dateTime.getDayOfMonth() == 29;
}

Alternatively, use MonthDay class, with MonthDay.of ( Month.FEBRUARY , 29 ).
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Edmonton" ) );
boolean isLeapDay = MonthDay.from ( today ).equals ( MonthDay.of ( Month.FEBRUARY , 29 ) );


Assuming that February, 29th, is the leap day works only when you also assume that the Gregorian calender system is used. Something that may cause already problems when your client is from Saudi Arabia … Therefore that method from Joda time that tells you whether a given day is the leap day for the given calendar system would make some sense (if it works transparently for all different calendar systems), but for some unknown reasons it was not added to the java.time package.

@tquadrat, good to know, thank you. for now we are dealing only with Gregorian calendars.

@Kirby So noted in my edit to your Question.


Is there a java.time equivalent of DateTime.dayOfYear().isLeap()?

The straight answer is No.  There isn't.
The current version of the question states that the OP uses the Gregorian calendar exclusively.  Even with this qualification, the answer is still No.  But you can easily check to see if the month/day is February 29th which is when a leap day will appear in the Gregorian calendar.
But what if we try to generalize this to non-Gregorian calendars?
First of all, we should observe that there are only 4 countries that have not adopted a Gregorian or modified1 Gregorian calendar as one of their officially recognized calendars.  These are Afganistan, Iran, Ethopia and Nepal.  (See the Wikipedia Civil Calendars for more details.)  So there are only 4 countries where leap day == 29th day of 2nd month doesn't work in at least one calendar.
What about those 4?

Afghanistan and Iran use the Solar Hijri calendar.  A leap day in this calendar is added to the last month of the year as the 30th day.

Ethiopia uses the Ethiopian calendar which has 13 months, the last being 5 or 6 days long.  A leap day in this calendar is the 6th day of the 13th month of an (Ethiopian) leap year.

Nepal has two official national calendars - Vikram Samvat and Nepal Sambat.  It is complicated.


1 - For example, the modern Japanese calendar use Gregorian days and months, and either Gregorian years or "regnal" era and year.  The Gregorian calendar was introduced in Japan in 1873 as part of the Meijin modernization.

Back to Java.  From what I can tell, Java doesn't support any of those  4 calendars at the moment.  On the other hand, it does support some Islamic calendars via the HijrahChronology class.
You can use Chronology.getAvailableChronologies() to get the available chronologies for your platform.  In Java 21 the "Umm Al-Qura calendar of Saudi Arabia" is the only Islamic calendar available by default.  It is a lunar calendar and has 11 leap years every 30 years, but it doesn't have the concept of as leap day.   The months of the year are either 29 or 30 days depending on the position of the moon, and no specific month is longer in a (lunar) leap year.

Either way, none of the relevant java.time classes expose methods for determining whether a day is a leap day.
There is a general solution, but it depends on your application knowing where a leap day would be added for all of the calendars that are going to be used.  That is a tractable problem if you are prepared to put in the research.

For what it's worth, The Umm Al-Qura calendar doesn't have a "leap day" concept.  Any of the 12 months can have either 29 or 30 days; so there's no particular month that's specifically longer in a 355-day year, as opposed to a 354-day year.

The shortest way I know of to write this is
return Year.isLeap(myDate.getYear());

assuming myDate is a LocalDate or a LocalDateTime, and Year has been imported as java.time.Year.  This pulls the year out of myDate as an int, then runs the leap-year check on it.
Update
Following OP's comment about wanting to know that the DAY is 29 February, I think the clearest way to write that is probably
return myDate.getDayOfMonth() == 29 && myDate.getMonth() == Month.FEBRUARY;


yeah, I'm specifically looking for whether the day is leap day rather than just leap year.

You mean you want to know whether the date is 29 February?  Sorry, that was unclear from the question.

sorry. I said in the question, "whether a given day is a leap day"

OK, I've never heard the term "leap day" to mean specifically 29 February, which is why I found your wording unclear.  I've updated my answer to include both interpretations.
